# SQL concat rows with same name value

Tags: sql

Let say I got table like that

```
Name | Stage | Date
-------------------
A    |  1st |  03092014    
A    |  2nd |  04092014    
A    |  3rd |  05092014    
B    |  1st |  06092014    
B    |  2nd |  08092014    
C    |  1st |  03092014
```

I wonder how to write SQL code wich would concat rows with same names and I will get something like that

```
Name | Stage          | Date
----------------------+-----------------------------
A    | 1st , 2nd, 3rd |  03092014 04092014 05092014    
B    | 1st, 2nd       |  06092014 08092014    
C    | 1st            |  03092014
```

Do I need to run through table with for cycle or is there better way to do that?

UPD:
I found out that I need to use this queries in Excel

Comment: Which data base you are using - SQL has multiple database if SQL server 2008 and above then you can refer FIDDLE HERE - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2803/7

Comment: Not sure what database server you want it for.

Comment: @MatsKindahl well, it's MS SQL

Comment: That makes a difference. `GROUP_CONCAT` exist MySQL, it is called `LISTAGG` in Oracle 11g, but AIUI, MS SQL do not have anything similar.

Comment: @DanilGholtsman - If you find my solution working for you than please mark the answer below.

Comment: @MatsKindahl oh, interesting.

Comment: @Murtaza yes, ofc! I check it as fast as I can!

Comment: @Murtaza well it's not working for sql-query in excel

Comment: @DanilGholtsman - I have given the solution for MS SQL 2005 and above. For Excel it wont work because CROSS APPLY is the feature for MS SQL 2005 and above.

Comment: @Murtaza oh, well, understood. could you help me with excel,if u could?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` for this:

```
SELECT Name
     , GROUP_CONCAT(Stage) AS Stages
     , GROUP_CONCAT(Date) AS Dates
  FROM my_table
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your question - I am assuming you are using MS SQL Server 2008 or higher to get he desired output

I would suggest to use CROSS APPLY here to concat the data -

Assumed Your Table name - `temptable`

```
SELECT distinct tblMain.Name, substring(stages, 1, len(stages)-1) as [Stage],substring(dates, 1, len(dates)-1) as [Date]  
FROM temptable tblMain
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Stage)) + ',' 
    FROM temptable tblDup1 WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE tblDup1.Name= tblMain.Name

     FOR XML PATH('')
) t1 (stages)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Date)) + ' ' 
    FROM temptable tblDup2 WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE tblDup2.Name= tblMain.Name

     FOR XML PATH('')
) t2 (dates)
```

Working [FIDDLE OUTPUT](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2803/7)

Comment: Interesting comparison on how you do it in SQL Server and MySQL (and hopefully somebody will add a Oracle 11g snippet as well). :)